# Does the sequence $\{f_n\}$ defined by $f_n = \frac{x^x}{n!}$ converge pointwise to $0$? How can I prove it?

Tags: real-analysis

I have worked on this problem since the election.  I don't know whether it was the election that caused me to lose track or what.  I really need to solve this problem.

Comment: Is $x$ a constant?

Comment: Asking if the sequence "converge[s] pointwise to $0$" suggests that this is a sequence of functions of $x$, and pointwise convergence involves asking about the real sequence $f_n(x)$ for each fixed $x$.

Comment: It doesn't imply it's a real sequence, necessarily. This one isn't on $x<0$, but it still converges pointwise to $0$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @mrob:  I think it is overly ambitious to assign definite values for $x^x$ when $x$ is a negative real number.  For example, what is $(-\pi)^{-\pi}$?

Comment: @hardmath $\pi^{-\pi}\cos(\pi^2)-i\pi^{-\pi}\sin(\pi^2)$

Comment: Are you sure it's $x^x$ and not $x^n$?

Answer (score 2):

Fix $x$. Then $x^x$ is some fixed number. Take the limit as $n\to \infty$ to get $0$.

I'm assuming you meant $f_n(x)=\frac{x^x}{n!}$.

Technically this depends on which domain you are requiring since $f_n(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: $f_n$ can be extended to cover $x=0$ by continuity. But the real question is: what is $x^x$ for negative $x$? :)

Comment: @Momo, you mean by forcing $f_n(0) = 0$? Doesn't that change the original sequence?

Comment: @Nameless $x^x\rightarrow 1$ when $x\rightarrow 0$, so one might define $f_n(0)=\frac{1}{n!}$

Comment: $x^x:=e^{(x \log x)}$. Depends which branch of $\log$ you choose, but no matter which you pick, it's just a constant for fixed $x$.

Comment: @Momo, right or the usual trick $f_n(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} f_n(x)$ as you suggested...

Comment: @mrob I know it can be defined as a complex number, but my point was that OP should specify the domain of the function in order to avoid an answer which might be more confusing than helpful (for example if the OP did not take a course in complex analysis)